# Layer incrementation as a function of QField spatial condition

Tags: qgis, qfield

In a QField project, I have two layers:
-One layer: MEASUREMENT POINT.
-One layer: PARCEL
In the MEASUREMENT POINT layer, I've created a ''REF_POINT'' layer, which is filled using the following expression:

```
aggregate(
    Parcel',
    concatenate',
    "Ref",
    filter:=intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent))
) || '-PS1'
```

On the other hand, I'd like this layer to fill up incrementally, so that if the number exists, we can have REF_PS2.
PS: Ref comes from the PARCEL layer

Comment: Question is very unclear and needs rewording. Is "Ref_Point" a layer (as you say) or an attribute. Be more explicit on the attributes of each layer and what they contain. Be more clear of what your required output is.

Comment: @Oisine, in fact "Ref_Point" is an attribute of the layer 'POINT_DE_MESURE'.

Comment: to summarize, I have two layers: (1) MEASUREMENT_POINT and (2) PARCEL

Comment: I fill the "Ref_Point" attribute with the following expression: aggregate(
    Parcel',
    concatenate',
    "Ref",
    filter:=intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent))
) || '-PS1'

Comment: @Oisine, my question is as follows: I'd like it if, when the "Ref_Point" attribute is filled in, if the number exists, we could have REF_PS2 or REF_PS3 if the second one exists.  REF is an attribute from the PARCEL layer.